# ORACLE: same query, same environment, same execution plan, same server, BUT DIFFERENT EXECUTION TIME

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

Can anyone imagine how a simple SELECT was executed 14 times, getting different execution times?

My SQL query looks like:

```
select count(*) 
from myTable_1 x
left join myTable_2 y ON x.id = y.id
where y.id is null;
```

These 2 tables contain more than 1.500.000 data. By LEFT Joining them I should get less.

At first execution, I force stopped after 40 sec.
At the second execution, after 7 sec I got a result set.
At the third execution, after 10 sec I got the same result set.
At 4th execution, I force stopped after >600 sec.
From 4th to 19th execution, I just force stopped because it last more than 1min, getting no result.

From my knowledge: As long as the query was fully executed (2nd execution) some "data" are kept in cache memory. At next execution(3rd,4th...) the duration of execution MUST be <= than the previous execution time .

What's wrong with it? 
It was executed on the same environment, having the same data into tables. 
I no longer think about hardware configuration, because it happen in the same environment. I do not see the use of "index hints". I cannot find an explanation about this different execution time...

Comment: This might be helpful: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54658/why-does-the-same-query-run-faster-the-second-time-i-run-it

Comment: Perhaps the table is being used for other purposes and you have concurrence issues.

Answer (score 0):

When your SQL is running query `v$session` to get your `sql_id`.

Once you have the `sql_id` query `v$sql` for this `sql_id`.

This view `v$sql` gives the disk reads, buffer gets, concurrency wait time, user io wait time, cpu time, elapsed time and so many other attributes of your sql execution. Extract this data and compare them. This will reveal where your sql is spending more time.

Also check what other DB activity is consuming database resources when you are performing your test. The aforementioned views can be used for this purpose also.

Also check if your server is used by any other databases or processes without proper max resource configuration.